# Add extra information after submitting form

Tags: django, forms

I have the following structure:

```
class FeatureType(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.type

class Feature(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    type = models.ForeignKey(FeatureType)
    premium = models.BooleanField("Premium Feature", default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
       return self.name
```

What I want to do is when the user is adding a vehicle (the app is for a vehicle inventory), there's a large textbox that will be used to get a list of features from another website by the user copying and pasting them there.

I'm doing fine so far, but what I don't know how to do is, for each feature that's parsed from the textbox, the user will be able to set the `type` this feature belongs to.  Here's my code so far:

```
vehicle_form = VehicleForm(request.POST or None)
photos = PhotosFormSet(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
features = FeaturesForm(request.POST or None)
if vehicle_form.is_valid() and photos.is_valid() and features.is_valid():
   vehicle = vehicle_form.save(commit=False)
   vehicle.save()
   if features.cleaned_data['external']:
       external_set = features.cleaned_data['external'].split('\r\n')
       for feature in external_set:
           #set featuretype somehow
           vehicle_feature, created = Feature.objects.get_or_create(name=feature
                  , type = featuretype)
           feature = vehicle.features.add(vehicle_feature)
   photos = PhotosFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=vehicle)
   photos.save()
```

So how can I enable choosing a feature type for each feature?

What I want to do, ideally, is to have existing features matched to the record...for those features that don't exist, the user will be redirected to another view that will enable him to set the `type` for each new feature and subsequently add it to the record.

**UPDATE 1**
I've modified the code a bit to look like this:

```
if features.cleaned_data['external']:
    new_features = []
    external_set = features.cleaned_data['external'].split('\r\n')
    for feature in external_set:
        try:
            vehicle_feature = Feature.objects.get(external_name = feature)
            feature = vehicle.features.add(vehicle_feature)
        except Feature.DoesNotExist:
            new_features.append(feature)
```

This takes care of getting the existing features....what I want to do now is to have all the features in `new_features` passed onto another form after the user saves the current record, where the user will enter further details for each feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your FeaturesForm you can add something like:

```
feature_type = forms.ChoiceField(label="Feature Type",
                           choices=FeatureType.objects.values_list('id', 'type'))
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what I'm looking for...all the features will be pasted into one large textarea

Comment: If you want to turn arbitrary, unstructured text into structured data, you'll need to write something a lot more complicated than a sexy forms.py file. I'd suggest thinking about forcing your users to enter data and give them categories, from a ChoiceField - as aeby suggests, to select from, before entering specific details for that type.